# How can I post-process a capture group while preserving others in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string with 3 capture groups and would like to preserve the first and third but perform a substitution on the second. How do I express this in sed?

Concretely, I have an input string like:

```
top-level.subpath.one.subpath.two.subpath.forty-five
```

And I want to preserve the part before the first `.`, shorten the middle part to the first letter of every word, and preserve the part after the last `.`. The result should look like:

```
top-level.s.o.s.t.s.forty-five
```

For preserving the capture groups, I have:

```
sed -r 's/([^.]*)(.*)(\..*)/\1...\3/'
```

which gets me:

```
top-level....forty-five
```

For converting something like `.subpath.one.subpath.two.subpath` to only initials, I have:

```
sed -r 's/(\.[^.])[^\.]*/\1/g'
```

which gets me:

```
.s.o.s.t.s
```

I'd like to essentially apply that second sed expression to capture group 2. Is there some way I can chain sed substitutions to perform that second substitution on only the second capture group while retaining the first and third?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `awk` solution that will work with any version of awk including MacOS:

```sh
s='top-level.subpath.one.subpath.two.subpath.forty-five'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for(i=2;i<NF;++i) $i=substr($i,1,1)}1' <<< "$s"

top-level.s.o.s.t.s.forty-five
```

This `awk` command uses `.` as input and output field separator. We loop through field position `2` to `last-1` and replace value of each field with the first character of that field. In the end we print full record.

---

A BSD `sed` solution to do the same:

```sh
sed -E -e ':x' -e 's/(.+\..)[^.]+\./\1./; tx' <<< "$s"

top-level.s.o.s.t.s.forty-five
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```sh
sed -E ':a; s/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/; ta' file > newfile         # GNU sed
sed -E -e :a -e 's/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/' -e ta file > newfile  # FreeBSD sed
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/QvfbfI). *Details*:

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax (`+` is now a *one or more* quantifier, `(...)` is parsed as a grouping construct)
- `:a` - sets an `a` label
- `s/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/` - finds zero or more chars, a `.` and then any single char other than a `.` (capturing this into Group 1), then one or more chars other than a `.`, and then matches and captures into Group 2 a dot char, the match is replaced with concatenated Group 1 + Group 2 values
- `ta` - goes to the `a` label upon successful replacement.

Comment: Should this work on macOS?
I get:


$ echo "top-level.subpath.one.subpath.two.subpath.forty-five" | sed -E ':a; s/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/; ta'
sed: 1: ":a; s/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+( ...": unused label 'a; s/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/; ta'
top-level.subpath.one.subpath.two.subpath.forty-five

Comment: @rajatsbugs MacOS has got FreeBSD, and it works there in a bit different form: `sed -E -e :a -e 's/^(.*\.[^.])[^.]+(\.)/\1\2/' -e ta`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In fact, POSIX states: "Editing commands other than `{...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and #` can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another editing command.". So Mac/BSD are following the standard. POSIX also says `-e arg` shall append the argument to the end of the script. So that would be the more portable syntax. Good answer though.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(\..*)\B.(.*\.)/\1\2/;ta' file
```

Capture the first and last periods and  hollow out the middle removing any side-by-side word characters.

---

Ameliorating @anubhava's sed answer:

```
sed -E 's/(\..)[^.]+\./\1./g;s//\1./g' file
```

Using the global flag and repeating the same substitution provides a 2 command solution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's not at all possible to run commands on the string/group captured by a single sub expression.

I would use this sed to achieve your task:

```
sed -E 's/(\.[^.])[^.]+\./\1./g; s/(\.[^.])[^.]+\./\1./g'
```

- The two `s` commands are identical, but must be run twice to modify adjacent fields, as the pattern begins and ends with a (literal) dot to avoid matching the first and last field.
- FWIW, this was consistently faster than `sed -E -e :goto -e 's/(\.[^.])[^.]+\./\1./; t goto'` in benchmarks - by 15% with GNU sed, and 25% with busybox sed.

There's also this method using GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([^.])[^.]*\./\1./2g'
```

- `Ng` starts global replacement at the Nth match.
- It's a documented feature in GNU sed, however POSIX says that combining a number with `g` produces undefined behaviour.
- It could be useful if you needed to keep more than the first field.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {beg=$1; end=$NF; $0=gensub(/([^.])[^.]+/,"\\1","g"); $1=beg; $NF=end} 1' file
top-level.s.o.s.t.s.forty-five
```